# route URL is not found in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I have configure routes like below in home-routing.module.ts

```
export const HomeRoutingModule: Routes = [
  {
    path:'',
    children:[
      {
        path:'',
        component:FirstComponent,
        data:
        {
          title: "first",
          urls: [{ title: "first component", url: "first" }]
        }
      },
      {
        path:'',
        component:SecondComponent,
        data:
        {
          title: 'second',
          urls: [{ title: "second component", url: "second" }]
        }
      }]
```

and my my home.module.ts is like bolow

```
imports: [
  CommonModule,
  HomeRoutingModule,
  RouterModule.forChild(HomeRoutingModule)
],
declarations: [FirstComponent, SecondComponent, ThirdComponent]
```

and my app-AppRoutingModule.module.ts is like below

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "first", component: FirstComponent },
  {
      path: "",
      children: [
        { path: "", redirectTo: "/first", pathMatch: "full" },
        { path: "first", loadChildren: "./home/home.module#HomeModule" },
      ]
    }]
```

and my application.module.ts is like below

```
@NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        FirstComponent,
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule
      ],
```

route `first` is working but where as i try  to open `second` route url it is not working
          but it showing error is like below

> core.js:1673 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'second'
>   Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'second'

Comment: what is the url you are trying ? you know you didn't set the path in your route ?

Comment: You want to lazy load your homeModule then why you are accessing FirstComponent from app-AppRoutingModule.module.ts

Comment: yeas I need lazy loadind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have created the demo for you. Here you can find how to implement lazy loading.

I have created two different Module File hence the routing file as well. One is `AppModule(app.module.ts)` and second is `HomeModule(home.module.ts)`.

The `HomeModule` is lazy loaded in the example.

In the `app.routing.ts`, you can find `root` level routing. And in home.routing.ts, you can find `FirstComponent` and `SecondComponent` routing.

**The example is same as your one.**

**Stackblitz Link**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-crbx3f

Comment: Y did you creare helloComponent.ts could you please tell me

Comment: It's temporary. Ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your path.

```
export const HomeRoutingModule: Routes = [
  {
    path:'',
    children:[
      {
        path:'first',
        component:FirstComponent,
        data:
        {
          title: "first",
          urls: [{ title: "first component", url: "first" }]
        }
      },
      {
        path:'second',
        component:SecondComponent,
        data:
        {
          title: 'second',
          urls: [{ title: "second component", url: "second" }]
        }
      }]
```

Answer (score 0):

In app-AppRoutingModule.module.ts second child route isn't defined. You should add

```
{ path: "second", loadChildren: "./home/home.module#HomeModule" }
```

And also you're paths are empty in children array

Comment: i'm trying do lazy loading

Comment: Try to simplify things. Only stuff you need to do is this



`const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: FirstComponent
  },
  {
    path: "first",
    loadChildren: "./home/home.module#HomeModule"
  },
  {
    path: "second",
    loadChildren: "./home/home.module#OtherModule"
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})`

Comment: And then in child component 

`const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", component: FirstComponent},

];

@NgModule({
    exports: [RouterModule],
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)]
})`

Answer (score 0):

Really confusing what you're trying to do but I guess you want:

```
{ path: "home", loadChildren: "./home/home.module#HomeModule" }
```

And then you want to navigate to `home/first` or `home/second`.

The way you have it now you'd have a route that's `first/first` which is kinda weird.

Comment: your solution throwing error                                                                       >Uncaught (in promise): Error: Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'HomeModule'
Error: Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'HomeModule'

Comment: @changeneed That's not down to my solution, that is something in your code, specifically `HomeModule`, that is causing it.